# Issue with join() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I'm attempting to bulk-download some csv files from a website. I've included a generic form of the first few lines of code I'm using below.

```
import urllib3
import os.path

def downLoadToDir(save_path,foo):

    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    os.makedirs("".join(save_path, foo)

    # Set up url and path for download
    VarUrl = "".join("http://url.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?t=", foo)
    VarPath = "".join(save_path, foo, '/',foo, '.csv')
```

Ideally this should set up a folder under the specified filepath, and set up two variables I use later. However, I keep getting this error:

```
File "url_download.py", line 10
VarUrl = "".join("url.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?t=", foo)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Based off of other examples I've seen online, this seems correct to me. Nothing seems to make it happy. Where am I going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Check the previous line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a right parenthesis at line:

```
os.makedirs("".join(save_path, foo)
```

Also, the `join` method takes only one list argument, and you are passing two arguments here. You should make the two strings a list before passing to `join` as one argument:

```
os.makedirs("".join([save_path, foo]))
```

The same issue goes for the following lines that also use `join`.

Comment: Jeez, that was obvious. Surprised my text editor did not catch that. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewHarper Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you think it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the bracket on line 7. Python is still looking for the close bracket and the `""` is not what the compiler expects to see.

use `os.makedirs("".join(save_path, foo))`